# Model Binder in Web Api does not bind my Fiddler Json post request

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, http-post, model-binding

I'm using Web Api with .Net Core. I have a cass that looks like this :

```
 public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have my action in a controller like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([ModelBinder] Event evt)
    {
    }
```

Then I compose a Post Request with Fiddler that looks like this:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:8186
Content-Length: 35
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
"Id":"1",
"ParentId":"0",
}
```

Now when the breakpoint hits my action, the model binder does not bind my object ! What could have gone wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `[FromBody]` attribute instead:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Event e)
{
    return Ok(e);
}
```

This will bind to your model correctly if you are sending json requests.

Comment: It worked in my pilot application. But after I merged my project to the main solution it stopped working ! The event parameter is null. and I receive an http 502 error back. and I have no idea what went wrong !!

Comment: It might be something blowing up in your `Startup.cs`. I think you should post a new question.